# How do I "unauthorize" a computer for use with iTunes when the computer is no longer around?

Tags: itunes

I assume Apple has a web site out there somewhere with a list of all my authorized computers but where is it?

Comment: Did unauthorizing all and then reauthorizing the one you want help you?

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to do it. I just didn't know you could do it right in iTunes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is the website that discusses the topic (with comments)](http://shannonclark.wordpress.com/2007/03/27/how-to-deauthorize-a-dead-computer-for-itunes/)

[Here's the info (Apple site) on how to unauthorize](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1420)

It basically sounds like you have to choose the option to unauthorize all of the computers, and then reauthorize the ones you want.

Comment: Of particular note: You can only "Deauthorize All" once a year.

Comment: Also, the option doesn't show up if you are not out of authorizations.